# Explain Java syntax

Tags: java, syntax

I'm looking at a piece of Java code that contains:

```
User rv = tmp != null && tmp.size() > 0 ? tmp.get(0) : null;
```

I'm not very strong with Java syntax. My interpretation is that `rv = tmp` as long as `tmp` is `null` `tmp`'s `size` is `> 0`, or else it equals `null`. Am I correct?

Comment: This is something you could test to find out on your own.

Comment: Probably if I wrote this I would use brackets to make it easier for a junior programmer to understand `User rv = (tmp != null && tmp.size() > 0) ? tmp.get(0) : null;`

Answer (score 7):

Here is the "anatomy" of this expression:

```
rv =                                // assignment of a conditional expression
    (tmp != null && tmp.size() > 0) // condition
?   tmp.get(0)                      // on true
:   null;                           // on false
```

This is a common way of ensuring that there would be no exception accessing element zero of the list: the condition ensures that `tmp` is not `null`, and also that the size is one or more.

Comment: Note that the code is almost illegible and needs parentheses at a minimum.

Comment: For added background information regarding ternary operators in java, click [here (wikipedia article)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java) and [here (java tutorial)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

Answer (score 3):

It's a [ternary conditional expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a#Java):

```
expr ? value-if-true : value-if-false
```

If `expr` is true, it evaluates to `value-if-true`, and otherwise it evaluates to `value-if-valuse`.

So, in this case, it's equivalent to:

```
 if (tmp != null && tmp.size() > 0) {
     rv = tmp.get(0);
 } else {
      rv = null;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
rv = ((tmp != null && tmp.size() > 0) ? tmp.get(0) : null);
```

if expression inside the inner brackets return true then rv will hold the value tmp.get(0) else it will hold the value null.

```
variable = expression ? a : b ;
```

is similar to

```
if expression == true 
  variable = a;
else 
   variable =b ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called a `ternary statement`.

Basically,

```
User rv = tmp != null && tmp.size() > 0 ? tmp.get(0) : null;
```

is a shorter way of writing:

```
        User rv;

        if (tmp != null && tmp.size() > 0)
            rv = tmp.get(0);
        else
            rv = null;
```

The ternary statement is not faster. Although, in some cases, using it makes your code more readable.

Comment: _in some cases, using it makes your code more readable._ - Not in this case though (if it had parentheses it would be better)